# Can't log into freenode

Tags: irc

I'm trying to use ChatZilla on Ubuntu with freenode but cannot login. I get a message that I am not using a valid command. I have not used my nickname in several months but some of the messages that came back indicate it is still registered.

I used the command `/msg nickserv nickname password`. So say my nickname was 'joe' and my password were '123456', I put in `/msg nickserv joe 123456` and I get back:

```
from(joe) 123456
to(NickServ) joe 123456
from(NickServ) Invalid command. Use /msg NickServ help for a command listing.
```

Comment: Sounds like you are using invalid commands.  Proper [research](http://superuser.com/questions/220245/how-do-i-register-a-nickname-on-freenode-s-irc-network-using-colloquy?rq=1) on a topic is required here.

Comment: Yes, I am using the wrong command and have not figured it out with an hour of research so am asking for help. Since I have done successfully logged in the past I'm a bit surprised.

Comment: *Which is the reason I provided you the correct command*  The comments in the other question made it clear, I originally intended, to link to the screenshot with the proper command.  despite that oversight on my part, the correct command, was clearly indicated in that existing question.

Comment: *Please just answer the question, then*. Not only does providing an oblique screenshot to someone who's clearly unfamiliar with IRC quite unhelpful, it leaves an actually-answered question floating around in the unanswered list to waste everyone else's time.

Comment: Ramhound - I appreciate your answer and effort. I did not recognize 'research' as a link with an answer so did not click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command is bad. If you want to identify to NickServ, the command is `/msg nickserv identify (password)`, registering is `/msg nickserv register (password) (email)`

"Joe" is not a valid command :)

Comment: Thank you! It just didn't click in my brain that identify=login